# flutter text color not changing by class

Tags: flutter, class, colors

I am new to flutter.
I have created class for Textstyle.
But its color is not changed.
I have created two classes, one for color variable
and other for textstyle.
but it not working. Please guide me.
attached full code here.

Thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "bbbbbbbbbbb",
            style: CtrBlblStyle(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CtrPublic {
  static Color blblTextColor = Colors.green;
}

class CtrBlblStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;

  CtrBlblStyle({
    this.color,
  })  : assert(true),
        super(
          color: color ?? CtrPublic.blblTextColor,
        );
}
```

Comment: you have given the color as black and the default color of `Text()` is black. so in this case try to change the color from black to another color and run your and see what happen.

Comment: Hi Saiful, thanks for your reply.  I change the color from black to green. but same issue again.  thanks for you co-operation

Comment: can i give a  solution in another way? if you interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this..

```
class CtrPublic {
  static const Color blblTextColor = Colors.red;
}
```

and then

```
class CtrBlblStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
 

  CtrBlblStyle({
    this.color = CtrPublic.blblTextColor,
  });
}
```